# How do I access the full size image taken with the camera from an Android Intent?

Tags: java, android

My button's onclick listener is as follows:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
      }

    });
```

And the result is handled as follows:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

          ImageView Preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PreviewImage1);
          Preview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
          Preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      }
   }
}
```

I got the thumbnail working but how do I access the full image so that I can do some manipulations? I want to avoid saving the file if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805822/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/

Getting the full-sized image is not possible without saving to a file. Also it won't be a good idea, because having so big Bitmaps in memory will soon cause Out of memory exception.

Comment: That saves the image to file. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Ah so... I think that is not possible. Also the default camera application don't work without SD card, because it has to save it...

Comment: But the preview image comes back okay without saving to file. So the only way to get the full image is to save to file, load from file, and then delete it? (Seems to be a hacky way to do it)

Comment: Yes, it is the only way - see my edit, added also an example with temporary file.

Comment: Now the app is crashing on this line: cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri); saying thread exited with uncaught exception. I put it into a try/catch block and it still crashing with the same error.

Comment: Had to remove the code for the thumbnail. Marked as best answer.